# How to set connection string for Entity Framework in console app

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I have a solution with 2 projects: asp app and console app. In my web.config on my asp project I have this:
 
`<connectionStrings>
   <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=PC-Flo\SQLExpress2008;Initial   Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=lol;Password=lolation" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>`

and my connection works.

Now I want to connect with my console app so in my App.config I put the same thing but I have this exception:

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig'
>   threw an exception

Thanks for your help.

**The App.config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=PC-Flo\SQLExpress2008;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=lol;Password=lolation" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: post your entire app.config file content

Comment: What is the EF version for both projects?

Comment: Oh, and please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585611/the-type-initializer-for-system-data-entity-internal-appconfig-threw-an-except

Comment: The version of Entity Framework for both projects is 6.0.0.0

Comment: You should take a look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801125/the-type-initializer-for-system-data-entity-internal-appconfig-threw-an-except

Answer (score 1):

I delete all my file and just put this inside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>

    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=PC-Flo\SQLExpress2008;Initial   Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=lol;Password=lolation" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

and finally it works. Thanks for your help.